# Functions and attributes of a person via dictionaries

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm really struggling trying to understand functions and how they can be used to create attributes or properties (in this case i'm tasked with a person)

The following is my code to declare the person in a dictionary,

```
def format(person):
    return "Name:\t" + person['name']

def display(person):
    print(format(person))

person = {'name':"Bilbo Baggins"}
```

I then can call the display to produce;

`Name = Bilbo Baggins`

I then have to add to the dictionary a property storing the weight and height (say both of which are 0 for now) of my person, which i have done by;

```
person['height'] = 0
person['weight'] = 0
```

I now need to create a function (called *create_person*) that has the 3 parameters (name, height and weight), and modify my earlier code to use this function and alongside printing **Name: Bilbo Baggins** also prints the weight(in kg) and height(in m).

The overall aim of this is to find out the BMI of a person, BMI is calculated by weight/height<sup>2</sup>. I also need to add a function that takes a single person object from the previous dictionary/function as a parameter and returns the BMI of the person. Is that possible through linking the two?

Comment: Have you considered creating a person class that has these functions as class methods?  Then you can have each person object have height and weight attributes, and then use these to calculate BMI.

Comment: Before everything - when creating function refrain from using the names of already built-in functions like `format()`.

Comment: @chris is that possible to then link to the dictionary i originally created? also do class method functions work the same way as a normal function?

Comment: @zwer my bad, i'm new with this and that's a thing i keep forgetting about, cheers for the heads up

Comment: @maltedg what do you mean link to the original dictionary?

Comment: @chris so for my first bit of code is there any way to return height: 000 and weight: 000, like it does with the names? just for purpose sake. I'm not sure if its possible to just return multiple statements straight off

Comment: So just `return "Name:\t" + person['name'] + ", Height:\t" + person['height'] + ", Weight:\t" + person['weight']` ?  This will output: `Name:    Bilbo Baggins, Height:    0, Weight:    0`

Comment: @chris yeah basically, i wasn't sure if the correct way would have been to start a new return indent for each property. Much appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, height, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
    # This is called when you print(PERSON OBJECT)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.height + " " + self.weight
    def BMI(self):
        return (self.weight/self.height)/self.height
```

This allows you to create a person like so:

```
person_one = Person("Bilbo", 177, 72.7)
print(person_one)
bmi = person_one.BMI()
```